# make an object file(*.o) compiled by gcc to be a binary file(*.bin)

Tags: c, macos, nasm, ld, apple-m1

I am learning the os tutorial.
https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial
After I using gcc convert my basic.c to basic.o,

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c basic.c -o basic.o
```

As describe in the toturial, I get a file named basic.o which is  an object file.
According to the next step, I need to convert basic.o to basic.bin.

```
ld -o basic.bin -Ttext 0x0 --oformat binary basic.o
```

The question is that my platform is Macbook Pro(M1) which os version is 12.4.

It seems that there are differences between macos ld and windows ld.

If I input `ld -o basic.bin -Ttext 0x0 --oformat binary basic.o`, I will get feedback as below.

```
ld: unknown option: -Ttext
```

What command about `ld` I need to convert basic.o to basic.bin on my platform?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are different, in fact gcc will be just a symlink to clang unless explicitly installed and told otherwise.

As for the -T option, I'm not too sure if you know what it means(if you don't, it will basically tell the linker to put the text section at address 0x0).

You might want to invest the time and look for how to build a linkerScript because you will probably going to use that later anyway.

[How to build a linkerScript](http://csci.viu.ca/%7Epwalsh/teaching/261/261/hc11/doc/ld_3.html)

If the link is dead at some point, you can just google "linkerScript ld" and it will show some tutorials.

Comment: This tutorial can help me solve the problem above on my Macbook M1?

Comment: Where can I inspect options of ld for my Macbook(M1)?

Comment: Note that I just realised I missed out from the answer but you will still need to install llvm and binutils(I'm not 100% sure it will work on M1 but on the site it says its supported) to do that make sure you have homebrew and do `brew install llvm binutils` and for the linkerscript you should include LD as '/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/ld.lld' or '/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/ld'

Comment: Thanks.@bitflip Can you give me the complete solution?